# colouring graph connections in R

Tags: r, graph, colors, tkplot

I built in R a graph and I succeeded in colouring some vertex using if statement in colour, i used the `tkplot` function to have a better visualization.
Now I have the following graph:

```
FROM    TO  
A   B
A   D
B   C
B   F
D   E
E   G
E   H
H   M
H   L
L   N
```

and the following vertex set

```
E  
L
```

I need to plot the graph coloring the connection incoming and outcoming in E and L in RED colour while all the other in BLACK.
To be clear I need in red the following connections lines

```
FROM    TO
D   E
E   G
E   H
H   L
H   M
```

Is there a solution for this?

Comment: Please provide full [reproducible code](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Reproducibility.html).

Comment: Hi Luke, the code is embedded in other calculation I presented just an example, data are extracted from a database and the I reproduce about 25 different graphs in different situazion, I will try to build the code for this specific example in order to help you in assisting me.

Comment: The code should also be _minimal_ - a little frame work which you can later apply to your real case. This includes necessary library calls, a dput to get the variables and so on. Makes it easier for all - and gets you answers. :-)

Comment: 'B = matrix(  c("A" ,"A", "B" ,"B","D","E", "E", "H", "H", "L", "B","D","C","F","E","G","H","M","L","N"), ncol=2)   
B<- data.frame(B)
grf<- graph.data.frame (B, directed =TRUE, vertices=NULL) 
error<-array("E", "L")'

Comment: I just added a messed comment to reproduce data :-)

Comment: `library(igraph)
B = matrix(  c("A" ,"A", "B" ,"B","D","E", "E", "H", "H", "L", "B","D","C","F","E","G","H","M","L","N"), ncol=2) 
B<- data.frame(B)
grf<- graph.data.frame (B, directed =TRUE, vertices=NULL) 
error<-array(c("E", "L"))
V(grf)$color <- ifelse(V(grf)$name %in% error, "red", "yellow")
tkplot(grf)`

Comment: I am stucked in understanding how to use `edge.color` parameter in tkplot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `edge.color` property isn't the only way. 
You can also set a `color` attribute to each edge, e.g. :
(more informations about `V(g)` and `E(g)` functions can be found [here](http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/igraph/docs/iterators))

```
library(igraph)

# initialize the graph
DF <- 
read.table(text=
"FROM TO  
A B
A D
B C
B F
D E
E G
E H
H M
H L
L N",header=T,stringsAsFactors=T)
g <- graph.data.frame(DF)

# set a color (black) attribute on all edges
E(g)$color <- 'black'
# set red color for the edges that have an incident vertex in the set 'E,L'
nodesSeq <- V(g)[name %in% c('E','L')]
E(g)[inc(nodesSeq)]$color <- 'red'

tkplot(g)
```

[image]

Comment: P.S. sorry I already had my code written when I noticed your sample data in the comments... Anyway, I don't think you'll have any problem in adapting my code to yours ;)

Answer (score 1):

Just create a color vector with the colours you want, corresponding to the edges in `B`:

```
library(igraph) 
B = matrix( c("A" ,"A", "B" ,"B","D","E", "E", "H", "H", "L", "B","D","C","F","E","G","H","M","L","N"), ncol=2) 
B<- data.frame(B) 
grf<- graph.data.frame (B, directed =TRUE, vertices=NULL) 
error<-array(c("E", "L")) 
V(grf)$color <- ifelse(V(grf)$name %in% error, "red", "yellow") 

col = rep("black", nrow(B)) 
col[B$X1 == "E" | B$X2 == "L"] <- "red" 
# or 
# col[B$X1 %in% c("E", "L") | B$X2 %in% c("E", "L")] <- "red" 
plot(grf, edge.color = col)
# or     
# tkplot(grf, edge.color = col)
```

Comment: This is a very good solution, I will compare both of them in terms of fastness, thanks lukeA